# how to inject RTF file to RichTextBlock in c#/xaml Windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, richtextbox, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to open the RTF file and then setting the the rich text on `RichTextBlock` ? 
`RichTextBox` has `Document.SetText()` method. How can I do same in `RichTextBlock` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765004/how-to-display-rtf-in-metro-app/15765218#15765218) from MSDN guys. `RichTextBlock` doesn't support RTF. It is totally disappointing thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must improve your question, It isn't clear sense.