# How to display rtf in metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

How can I show rtf strings in a RichTextBlock (or any other UI text element)? There's no rtf property I could use (different from .net I think). And if I bind the string to the normal text property I only get the rtf code itself.

So is there a way to do this? Otherwise I'd display the string as HTML in a WebView element. But I'd prefer a RichTextBlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `RichEditBox` instead of `RichTextBlock`. You can inject RTF with [RichEditBox.Document.SetText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext.aspx) method. `RichTextBlock` isn't an RTF control and doesn't understand RTF. The `RichEditBox` is the only in-box control which supports RTF. If you don't want to use that then you would need to parse the RTF yourself and create the block elements for the `RichTextBlock`.