# How to create a WinRT Book reader application

Tags: windows-runtime, html-parsing, rtf

I'd like to create an application that receives formatted text (RTF) or html, renders it an show it page by page..

Is there any control that aims to do that?

I tried to use the RichEditBox control to load a file but it stucks during the operation:

```
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"myFile.rtf");

using (var memstream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            MainText.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.ApplyRtfDocumentDefaults, memstream);
        }
```

I tried to load an HTML file this way:

```
 var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"myFile.htm");
 var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
 string app;
 using (StreamReader rStream = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
        {

            app = rStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        myWebView.NavigateToString(app);
```

But I cannot find a way to "count" the lenght of the parsed text to chunk it in pages..

There is any other way or library to do that? Any example online?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your HTML contents in pages then you can use `RichTextBlock` with `RichTextBlockOverflow`. RTF is not supported to `RichTextBlock`.

[how to inject RTF file to RichTextBlock in c#/xaml Windows store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872580/how-to-inject-rtf-file-to-richtextblock-in-c-xaml-windows-store-app)

[Showing Html in WinRT with RichTextBlock or other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088034/showing-html-in-winrt-with-richtextblock-or-other-component)

[XAML text display sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-text-display-sample-2593ba0a)